# Gratis Windows program to burn large MKV files to old style CD movies

Tags: windows, gratis, video, media-converter

I have some holiday movies, generally, one 3 gB, one > 10gB as MKV files and want to give copies to a friend.

Said friend is very old school, so they need to be burned as movie standard (*.VOB?), not as MKV.

I have a lot of old CD banks lying around & 760mB is enough to view holiday movies although I could burn to DVD if it must be so.

What gratis Windows app can I use (and how, if it is complicated)?

Answer (score 1):

A standard DVD is only valid if it follows the specifications. The video resolutions are constrained to PAL or NTSC and the disc should really be a DVD. That's the constraint of your first requirement. [DVD Styler](https://www.dvdstyler.org/en/) is a fairly simple app that can do this for you.

If the dvd-player/tv of your friend is 'smart' enough it might be possible that any disk with a movie file (like your mkv) will play just fine without too much hassle. Quality wise that will give a better result to, so that is worth exploring I think.

Comment: "`support of AVI, MOV, MP4, MPEG, OGG, WMV and other file formats`" - do you know which format is plain dumb old video, like an 80s DVD player?

Comment: Is that a single file > 10 GB?

Comment: DVD is from the 90s, so I think you'll be hard pressed to find a 80s player.